# Expected Time in a Graph

Tags: probability, probability-theory, graph-theory

I am having a Graph with `N` node connected with bidirectional road having some weight i.e time to travel an edge , I random choose a vertices `Next` , and start walking toward it , such that time to reach at `Next` will be minimum , after reaching `Next` , i randomly choose another vertices and start walking towards it following the minimum path.

I repeat the process **P** times. What would be expected time to complete my walk.I chooses the vertices with equal probability , initially i wast at node 1.

Let `S` be summation of time taken to complete the process i.e summation of time taken in all possible walk following the above condition.

How to find the expected value of time take in order to complete the process ?

Comment: What is the relation between "weight" and "time to reach" in this description?

Comment: @HenningMakholm updated

Comment: Is the graph also chosen randomly, along with the weights on its edges?

Comment: @MishaLavrov yes it's random generated graph

Answer (score 1):

Since each of your waypoints is chosen at random in the same way, repeating the process $P$ times simply multiplies the expected time by $P$, due to linearity of expectation.

So we just need to find the expected length of the shortest path between two vertices in a randomly weighted graph. This is solved in [a paper by Janson](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/combinatorics-probability-and-computing/article/one-two-and-three-times-log-nn-for-paths-in-a-complete-graph-with-random-weights/AFD1356F021A23EE7A722F6FDE867F7D), who proves that if the weight of an edge is distributed uniformly on $[0,1]$, the expected time is $(1+o(1)) \frac{\log n}{n}$.

How is this affected by different weight distributions? The key property that the proof relies on is that if $\mathbf X_1, \dots, \mathbf X_n$ are, for example, uniform on $[0,1]$, then as $n \to \infty$ the value of $$n \cdot \min\{\mathbf X_1, \dots, \mathbf X_n\}$$ converges in distribution to an exponential random variable with mean $1$. The proof is not hard: we have $$\Pr\left[\min_i\{\mathbf X_i\} \ge \frac{t}{n}\right] = \prod_{i=1}^n \Pr[\mathbf X_i \ge \frac tn] = \left(1 - \frac tn\right)^n \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} e^{-t}.$$ The same argument works if the edge weights have a common distribution $\mathbf X$ for which $\Pr[\mathbf X < \epsilon] \sim \epsilon$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

More generally, as long as $\mathbf X$ isn't bounded away from $0$, we can compute $$\lambda = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\Pr[\mathbf X < \epsilon]}{\epsilon}$$ and conclude that the expected time to get from one vertex to another is $(\lambda^{-1} + o(1))\frac{\log n}{n}$.

This allows us to consider random weighted graphs where edges fail to be present with some probability; we can model this as being assigned weight $1000$ or something. (For example, if the edge is present with probability $\frac12$ and its weight has a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ in that case, we'll get $\lambda=\frac12$, doubling travel time.)

The result doesn't hold if, for example, the edge weights are distributed uniformly on $[1,2]$. (In this particular example, you realize that you never want to travel along an indirect path: it will always cost at least $2$, while the travel along the direct path is at most $2$.)